# How to make a variable name dynamic based on function's parameter?

Tags: python, pandas, variables

I have a function I use to make duplicate rows in Pandas in order to have in each row a different value that were together before

```
GRI_Code     ADX_Code
  102        S1.2\nS1.1\nS5.1\nS5.2
  102\n405   S4.2\nS4.3\nS4.1
  103        E7.2\nE7.3\nE7.1\n\n\nS9.2\nS9.1\nS10.2\nS10.1\n
  302        E3.1\nE3.2\n\n
```

the method I use is:

```
def separate_code(self, df, column, delimiter):
    df = df.assign(GRI_Code=df[f'{column}'].str.split(delimiter)).explode(f'{column}')
    
    return df
```

When I call the funtion:

```
df = separate_code(df, column='GRI_Code', delimiter="\n")
```

My output is:

```
GRI_Code    ADX_Code
   102      \n\nS1.2\nS1.1\nS5.1\nS5.2
   102      S4.2\nS4.3\nS4.1 
   405      S4.2\nS4.3\nS4.1
   103      E7.2\nE7.3\nE7.1\n\n\nS9.2\nS9.1\nS10.2\nS10.1\n
   302      E3.1\nE3.2\n\n
```

I will be using this method on other dataframes with different column names, I would like to know how can I add the `column=` in a dynamic way, if I use the variable `column` instead of `GRI_Code=` it is going to create a new column and return the same values in the same row as a list, I don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary and parameter expansion:

```
def separate_code(self, df, column, delimiter):
    return df.assign(**{column: df[f'{column}']...})
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, it separates the values that are together, but  on the rows where the new separated values are, I don't get the same other values from previous rows.

Comment: Well, I didn't check anything about the logic, I just answered the primary question: "*I would like to know how can I add the column= in a dynamic way*" ;)

Comment: Sir mozway is there any other way than this `df1.isnull().values.any()` for checking null values in a dataframe in single value?

Comment: seems like a good approach to me

Comment: Why? What is wrong with your way?